# Passing 2D vector by reference

Tags: c++, vector, reference

I haven't touched c++ for a while and I just encountered a very weird problem when passing 2D vector by referrence, it's described in the `main` function:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int> > permute(vector<int> &num) {


    vector<vector<int> > result;
    //I intentionally omit the codes for permutation,
    //only pushing the original one to the result
    result.push_back(num);

    return result;


    }

    //print the permutation, I want to pass by referrence
    void printPerm(vector<vector<int> >  &result) {

    for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {

        for(int j=0; j<result[i].size(); j++) {

            cout << result[i][j]<<" ";
            }
        }

    }

};

int main() {

    vector<int> old;
    old.push_back(1);
    old.push_back(2);
    old.push_back(3);

    Solution sol;

    //this gives me error for no matching function
    //call, candidate argument doesn't match
    sol.printPerm((sol.permute(old))); 

    //but the one below works!

    vector<vector<int> > result = sol.permute(old);

    sol.printPerm(result);


}
```

Comment: If you can use c++11, you can use the new http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with vectors (or any specific types for that matter); it only has to do with return values and references. See http://codepad.org/4PNCcGs5 for a simpler program that has the exact same issue.

Comment: @delnan yep, I didn't know what causes it so I decide to post entire thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `const` to result to allow binding to rvalue

```
 void printPerm(const vector<vector<int> >  &result) 
 //             ^^^^^^
```

Comment: thanks! but what if `printPerm` wants to modify result?

Comment: @Arch1tect: In that case you wouldn't be passing the return value of a function.

Comment: @VaughnCato do you mean I can't ? So in that case I have to do it in two steps? I mean two lines of codes.

Comment: @Arch1tect: If the function was going to modify the argument, then presumably you would want the result of that modification.  If you were just passing the result of another function instead of passing a variable, then you'd have no way to see the changes to the argument.

Comment: @VaughnCato alright... thanks. Though I still feel this design isn't very flexible or convenient..

Comment: @Arch1tect: Could you give a practical example of how a different design would be better?